# Joomla to Drupal migration problem

Tags: drupal, migration, joomla

AFter migrating a joomla 1.5 site to Drupal 6 by using [Joomla to Drupal](http://drupal.org/project/joomla) module. While importing I ticked full HTML. Now some of the pages have are annoying codes as shown below:

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]>

Normal
0
21

false
false
false

TR
X-NONE
X-NONE

MicrosoftInternetExplorer4


<![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]>

DefSemiHidden="true" DefQFormat="false" DefPriority="99"
LatentStyleCount="267">

UnhideWhenUsed="false" QFormat="true" Name="Normal"/>

UnhideWhenUsed="false" QFormat="true" Name="heading 1"/>
```

I think they are copied and pasted from MS Word. How could I fix these?
Thanks

Comment: HOw many nodes did you create?

Comment: Approximately how many nodes do you think are effected? Is this site for yourself or does someone else own the content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of 2 possibilities:

1. Try re-importing with 'filtered html', this will strip non-approved tags (filtered html can be customised to allow certain tags e.g. <img>). I don't know if the import module has a setting to choose this or not.
2. Use a rich text editor on drupal, and manually edit each node. I know the WYSIWYG editor ckeditor has a config parameter to force pasting into the textbox to be plain text

Comment: actually first option didn't work and manual option will take too long.

Comment: @Gok Demir, can you explain why the first option did not work? Is there an option to specify another filter for the 'body' other than 'full html'? A customised filter (allowing only the tags you specify) sounds like the perfect solution. Obviously with 900 nodes, an automatic solution is going to be best here, thus ruling out option 2.

Comment: I dont know why but didnt worked. It tuns out that I will do it manually. Anyway thanks for the reply.